# Can I have multiple subscriptions to the same product with the one account?

Tags: android, google-play, subscription

I'm a developer working on an educational services app for students.

My service has an app for students and an app for parents.

The parent app has a feature that allows parents to subscribe to a student's membership.

One parent can be associated with multiple students. I want to create a flow where a parent purchases multiple one-month subscriptions for multiple students.

Does Google Play support multiple subscriptions to the same subscription under one account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Here] You can see the subscription configuration while creating trough Google Play Console. As you can see there is no switch like "**allow multiple purchase**" so I don't think that it will be possible to subscribe multiple times to an active subscription. Also I can say that google doesn't allow you to subscribe a subscription multiple times trough app and it says "Already Subscribed"

**As a result**, Google Play doesn't support multiple subscriptions to the same subscription under one account. Unfortunately you need to change your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not allow multiple subscriptions to the same Subscription product.

I'd recommend creating bundles of subscriptions - 2 one-month subscriptions for multiple students, 3, 4 etc. and offering a bundle with entitlement to multiple seats.